# How to invoke two run methods in one java file

Tags: java, android

below is the code where i need to invoke 2 run methods for 2 different threads any way this can be done. please help on this.

```
public class QuestionList extends ListActivity implements Runnable {
                //This below thread will call the run method
        Thread thread = new Thread(QuestionList.this);
            thread.start();

         //can i have one more thread which call run1() method any idea

}


public void run() {


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two `run()` methods of course, and I suggest not using the same for both `Thread`s (with a of `if()` statement to determine which behaviour to apply).

Instead you should create two distinct classes (why not inner classes) to implement these distinct behaviours. Something like:

```
public class QuestionList extends ListActivity {
    class BehaviourA implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
        }
    }

    class BehaviourB implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
        }
    }

    private void somewhereElseInTheCode() {
        BehaviourA anInstanceOfBehaviourA = new BehaviourA();
        Thread threadA = new Thread(anInstanceOfBehaviourA);
        threadA.start();

        BehaviourB anInstanceOfBehaviourB = new BehaviourB();
        Thread threadB = new Thread(anInstanceOfBehaviourB);
        threadB.start();
    }
}
```

The good thing with inner classes is that they can access to the members of `QuestionList`, and this seems to be what you are willing to do.

Comment: anInstanceOfBehaviourA how will you create a child instance in parent for Thread threadA = new Thread(anInstanceOfBehaviourA);
        threadA.start();

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you. Another way is to have `class BehaviourA extends Thread` instead of `class BehaviourA implements Runnable`. This way you create a `Thread t = new BehaviourA()` and you call `t.start();`. This is the way I do in most cases. I used `implements Runnable` to stay as close as possible to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class QuestionList extends ListActivity {
                    //This below thread will call the run method
            Thread1 thread1 = new Thread(this);
            thread1.start();

            Thread2 thread2 = new Thread(this);
            thread2.start();


    }

    class Thread1 implements Runnable
    {
       public void run() {


       } 
    }

   class Thread2 implements Runnable
   {
       public void run() {


       } 
   }
```